# airflow webserver Workers terminating due to signal 11

Tags: python, macos, airflow, apple-m1

I'm trying to start the airflow webserver with an existing application and the latest version (2.2.2).  The executor is set as LocalExecutor, the datastore is Postgres, Python v3.9.  Upon start up, it launches 4 workers which promptly die.  It then spins its wheels continually trying to restart them.

Here's an example of the messages showing a worker starting and dying with signal 11 (segmentation violation).  This is all within a second of starting.

```
Using worker: sync
[2021-11-30 17:29:31 -0500] [12529] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12529
[2021-11-30 17:29:31 -0500] [12530] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12530
[2021-11-30 17:29:31 -0500] [12531] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12531
[2021-11-30 17:29:31 -0500] [12532] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12532
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120

settings.prepare_engine_args(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=12529

[WARNING] Worker with pid 12529 was terminated due to signal 11
```

Any suggestions on how to debug these workers?

Comment: Addition info:  I'm on a MacOS Monterey (v12.0.1) with an Apple M1 chip.  This seems to be relevant in other posts.  The specific error is `thread_get_state(PAGEIN) returned 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port`

Comment: hello. any updates on this?

Comment: i'm experiencing this issue on one of my repos after downloading docker. Still trying to get to the bottom of it. Running on an intel i7 chip MacOS.

Comment: I was able to solve this by changing the dependencies in my Pipfile. Basically copied the packages required for composer-2.0.2-airflow-2.1.4 (see link below). I was not able to narrow it down to the specific package that was causing it, but by making sure all the versions were specified for each package and each dependency for airflow 2.1.4 solved this issue. Took me like 4 days to solve this.

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on trying to run Airflow directly on my M1 Mac.  I suspect it has something to do with the emulator for the M1 chip, but don't know for sure.  I fell back to running Airflow in Docker.  It takes a very long time to start, but does run OK that way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).